# How to stop webdriverIO script if any "expect" assertion fails?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, webdriver-io

Even after my expect assertion failed my script is executing next 'it' block. How can I stop execution of script if any test case is failed in my webdriverIO

code:

```
it('6. Confirm flight IATA code and Airline name',async()=>{
     await expect(cargodamagePage.flightIATA).toHaveValue('ERV')
     console.log("The flight IATA code is",await cargodamagePage.flightIATA.getValue());
})
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a `bail` option you can set in your `wdio.conf.js` file. If you set it to `1`, it will stop all tests if after a single test failure:

https://webdriver.io/docs/options#bail

Comment: @ Kevinlamping I have set my Bail to 1 but still after failed test cases code is running normally. My project framework is "Jasmine"

Comment: I have set my Bail to 1 but still after failed test cases code is running normally. My project framework is "Jasmine" –@Kevinlamping

Comment: Can you open an issue on the WebdriverIO github page then?
https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/issues/new?assignees=&labels=Bug+%F0%9F%90%9B%2CNeeds+Triaging+%E2%8F%B3&template=bug_report.yml&title=%5B%F0%9F%90%9B+Bug%5D%3A+%3Ctitle%3E